# Redirect URL gets rewritten on Azure

Tags: redirect, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have an APIController that needs to redirect to another service that may have a different subdomain. Simplified code:

```
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage DoSomething() {
    HttpResponseMessage response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Moved);
    string hostname = GetHostname();
    response.Headers.Location = new Uri("https://" + hostname + "/new_path" + Request.RequestUri.Query);
    return response;
}
```

The redirect should go either to a different subdomain or the same subdomain but a different port, depending on the staging environment where it runs. It may also go to an IP if I run it locally. GetHostname will always return the correct hostname and if I run it locally everything works as expected. However as soon as I run it on Azure I get a redirect to an IP address which isn't reachable (e.g. `http://100.1.2.3/new_path`). Is there any way to prevent this and get the original unchanged URL?

Comment: Can you share your `GetHostName()` method implementation?

Comment: `GetHostName()` just returns a setting that depends on the staging environment. I've also checked that it is correct already, so it's not really relevant here. I can replace it with `string hostname = "foo.mydomain.com";` and get the same results.